# Trouble with Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Basically i'm having trouble with something that i'm sure is super duper simple but I just don't know what to call it and therefore I am having trouble searching for an answer. :(

Basically, say I've declared an object, i.e `var meow = {};` and then i decide to create an object within that by doing something like `meow.cutekitten = {};` this is all straight forward and i end up with an object called `cutekitten` within that.

My issue is, what if I've declared `cutekitten` as a variable and i want to use the contents of that variable as the name of this new object rather than the variable name?

Comment: To set an object property you don't use 'var' again. So not: 'var meow.cutekitten = {};' but just 'meow.cutekitten = {};'

Comment: fixed sorry, that isn't the problem though but thanks ;)

Comment: also @Aesthete It's not an issue with a specific piece of code this is a general arrays/objects issue. See sq2's answer if it helps you understand what my issue was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var propertyName = "cutekitten";
var meow = {};
meow[ propertyName ] = {};
```